# How to check if the user has clicked a button in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am scraping a website which has a form with a captcha. The user would select the options through the select box, enter the Captcha manually and click on Go button ( Please refer the screenshot).

Now, once the user has clicked Submit button, I would like to know through Selenium Webdriver.

Here is part of the code in Python :

```
url= 'http://services.ecourts.gov.in/ecourtindia/cases/s_order.php?state=D&state_cd=26&dist_cd=9'

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

try:
    time.sleep(10)
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "submit1")))
except Exception as e:
    print str(e)
```

[image]

Comment: No, there is no redirect. After Submit, a table is displayed with data below the Submit button ( which typically takes few seconds to load)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you click on submit button , I am assuming (which is highly likely) that redirection occurs.

after click on submit button , your will be redirected to a new Page which will have some contents, right?

What you have to do here :

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((Locator, "value"))).text
```

and you already know the value , which will be expected value.

Now you can assert these two value.

**UPDATE** :

As you have mentioned, that a table appears , now what you can do here is :

wait for visibility of table and get the heading of table using .text and assert the value.

Comment: It doesnt redirect to a new page. It loads the data on the same page after validation which typically takes a few seconds). Here is the link : http://services.ecourts.gov.in/ecourtindia/cases/s_order.php?state=D&state_cd=26&dist_cd=9

Comment: WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'showList')))

Comment: After that you can use :  case = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((BY.XPATH,'//th[text()='Case Type/Case Number/Case Year']'))).text to get the text of second column of the table , note that you already know the text , here after you can assert.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @cruisepandey

Comment: @cruisepandey As per the documentation `visibility_of_element_located(locator)` can't accept 2 arguments as in `EC.visibility_of_element_located((locator of new page after redirection, "value"))`

Comment: @DebanjanB ::   WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'showList'))) , I believe it does. Please have a look.

Comment: @cruisepandey See your line of code within the answer `element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((locator of new page after redirection, "value"))).text`

Comment: @DebanjanB :   locator of new page after redirection means the type of locator and value means its value , anyway I have changed it.

Answer (score 1):

I've been through a similar problem a time ago, but in my case the page could load 2 different templates without reloading, sometimes a table was displayed and sometimes a modal telling something like "there is no data"

So I couldn't search for a new element that would appear on the page, my solution was to insert my own element (via javascript) on the page whenever the user clicked at the button and then search for this new element.

Here is an example:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# first you need to get your button at python to inject the javascript
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("element_xpath")


# here is a sample of an element you can create via js (this one is a hidden input)
javascript = "let element = arguments[0];\
              element.addEventListener('click', function() { \
                    let input = document.createElement('input'); \
                    input.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');  \
                    input.setAttribute('id', 'my_input'); \
                    document.body.appendChild(input); \
              });"
                            
        
# finally you send the javascript to your webbrowser with execute_script
driver.execute_script(javascript,element)

# then you will be able to wait the element to be created 
#(30 is te timeout in seconds, you should adjust as you need)
hiddenInput = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="my_input"]')
)
```